# Saving file to the same location in macOS app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

I have a problem of saving file to the same location in macOS app. I receive

```
ImageIO: IIOImageWriteSession:111: cannot create: '/Users/user/Documents/image.jpg.sb-c437170c-8GQ3pE'
         error = 1 (Operation not permitted)
```

I have "Save as" feature and it works well. As far as I understand, you can't just save file without NSSavePanel. So what should I use to save file to the same location?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to save? How do you save with `NSSavePanel`? Did you read the same file and how?

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved this issue. 
The right solution is to use **security-scoped bookmarks** for saving file. Created bookmark gives you permission to save file to the same location without NSSavePanel.